# Contour plot on the surface of a 3D cylinder

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, voxel, cylindrical

Because of [your great help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47333811/how-do-i-create-a-surface-plot-with-matplotlib-of-a-closed-loop-revolve-about-an) I can now plot a 3D cylinder with a hole inside :)
This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mlp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d as axes3d


inner_radius = 100
outer_radius = 300
height=50

# input xy coordinates
input_xy = np.array([[ri,0],[ra,0],[ra,h],[ri,h],[ri,0]])
# radial component is x values of input
r = xy[:,0]
# angular component is one revolution of 30 steps
phi = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 30)
# create grid
R,Phi = np.meshgrid(r,phi)
# transform to cartesian coordinates
X = R*np.cos(Phi)
Y = R*np.sin(Phi)
# Z values are y values, repeated 30 times
Z = np.tile(xy[:,1],len(Y)).reshape(Y.shape)


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection='3d')
#ax2 = fig.add_axes([0.05,0.7,0.15,.2])

#ax2.plot(xy[:,0],xy[:,1], color="k")
ax.set_zlim(0,200)
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, alpha=0.5, color='lightgrey', rstride=1, cstride=1)



plt.show()
```

The next very important step for me would be to plot on the top surface (or maybe in 3d if it is possible) a countor plot. It should look like this (it also can be just in 2d):
[Contour Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBhF2.jpg)

Applied to my plot it would look somehow like this:[Contour plot on my example code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBCRc.png)

I found something which looks similar to my problem [How to plot contour lines on a surface plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49399748/how-to-plot-contour-lines-on-a-surface-plot-4d/51306259?noredirect=1#comment89590056_51306259) but unfortunately I don't understand the code.
Best regards !

Update: Here is a draft of how I imagine it should look like:[Target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V23JB.png)

I hope somebody knows how to handle this problem.

Comment: `ax.voxels` will produce voxels; so if you don't need them, don't use them. Instead you may be looking for something like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47333811/how-do-i-create-a-surface-plot-with-matplotlib-of-a-closed-loop-revolve-about-an)?

Comment: Thank you so much, it helped me a lot. Now I have a 3d plot of a cylinder with a hole. I have one furher question. Can I ask it here in this post or should I ask a new question? Best regards