# Matplotlib: Cyclic Contour Plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour

I already asked a question here: [Contour plot on the surface of a 3D cylinder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51188648/contour-plot-on-the-surface-of-a-3d-cylinder)

But I didn't get an answer so I am trying another approach.
I would like to plot a contour plot with data across the radius. I think I almost did it but there is one problem. First my code and how the plot looks like now: [Contour Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AksvC.jpg)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xlist = np.linspace(-40, 40)
ylist = np.linspace(-40, 40)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(xlist, ylist)
Z = np.sqrt(X ** 2 + Y ** 2 )
plt.figure()
#These are my values for a certain radius 
levels = [15, 17, 18, 20, 21, 23, 25, 26, 28, 29, 31, 33, 34, 36, 37]
contour = plt.contourf(X, Y, Z, levels)
contour_filled = plt.contourf(X, Y, Z, levels)
plt.colorbar(contour_filled)
plt.show()
```

My problem is the radius. I would like to visualize a certain value (e.g. 15) on the radius of 150 as a certain color (e.g. blue).In my plot the value 15 represents the radius 15. I hope you guys know what I mean... Maybe the function contour is the wrong approach?? But is there a possibility to get a similar plot (with all the nice filled colors) with another function?

Best regards

Comment: You can plot a red circle with radius 15 on top of your plot. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer! No I mean I need a circle at radius 150 ( which should represent the value 15 with a color), than a circle at radius 170 (which should represent the value 17 with another color), than a circle at radius 200 (which should represent the value 18 with another color again) and so on... Ideally it should look like a filled contour plot.

Comment: I think, what you describe is exactly what you already have. I don't see the difference.

Comment: In my case the levels I put in represents a radius.E.g.:  In my plot I have the level 15 which is at the same time the radius 15. I need a plot ( in best case it would look like a contour plot) where I can assign values like 15 to a certain radius like 150. It means: At radius of 150 should be a circle (e.g. blue color) and right next to the plot a legend with a blue color and the value 15. I hope u know what I mean ^^ Thanks